# Are we supposed to be seeing tags that have been merged/synonym with other tags?

Tags: support, tags

Under the [tags tab](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=popular) there are tags such as [switches](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/switches) that shows up but is a synonym of [switch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/switch). Are we supposed to be seeing both there? It seems to make it a little difficult to navigate tags.

Comment: @Jeff You beat me too it, I went to remove the bug tag and it was no where to be seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, synonyms need to show up -- otherwise people asking questions would have no idea that the other form is supported or available.

Comment: Good enough answer for me. Although with the way they seem to be using synonyms it does seem redundant in some cases. Example, surely someone who was looking for "switches" wouldn't have any issue with only seeing "switch".

Answer (score 0):

*I started this as a comment to Jeff's answer, but it became a bit long.. :-)*

Probably just me, but I don't understand the need for the synonyms. If somebody starts typing `swĭ` she'll see `switch` and `switches` as suggestions. And instead of just having one clear tag for it, some people will choose `switch` and others `switches`. Can't we (automagically) edit the least preferred to the preferred one, so that we keep the number of tags under control? At least a warning about a deprecated tag would be nice.
I'm also thinking about the other question on tags where the example of `D-class` and `class-D` is given. Ideally it should be impossible to create one of them.

Comment: a synonym will automatically rename switch to switches if that is the synonym. The system does not do anything for the user to need to see, moderators can easily add synonyms and users, such as yourself(shouldn't you be relaxing though instead of working so hard), can suggest them and vote on them automating the process.